# Launcher doesn't show

Tags: 16.04, unity, launcher

I'm using ubuntu 16.04, and the launcher doesn't show anymore. I've tried many things on the web, such as apt-get install --reinstall ubuntu-desktop and rm -rf ~/.config or dconf reset -f / or activating the unity plugin in ccsm, but it still doesnt display the launcher after reboot. Any help please?